# Why does Scrapy crawl only one page?

Tags: scrapy

I'm trying to test Scrapy for crawling web pages and I do not understand why my crawler is crawling only one page, I've tried to comment both rules and allowed_domains without success. I guess there's something stupid I'm missing any help would be appreciate.

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor

class NYSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "ny"
    allowed_domains = ["nytimes.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.nytimes.com/"]

    rules = (
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('/2012', )),  callback='parse_article'),
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('/page', ))),
    )

    def parse(self, response):
        print 'page '+response.url

    def parse_article(self, response):
        print 'article '+response.url
```

Any sample of a program doing a crawl of an entire site would be welcomed too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You use a callback for the rule. From the [docs](http://readthedocs.org/docs/scrapy/en/latest/topics/spiders.html?highlight=rule#scrapy.contrib.spiders.Rule):

> follow is a boolean which specifies if links should be followed from
>   each response extracted with this rule. If callback is None follow
>   defaults to True, otherwise it default to False.

So you should do

```
 Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('/2012', )),  callback='parse_article', follow=True)
```

Additionally to this issue, another IMO might be your [parse method](http://readthedocs.org/docs/scrapy/en/latest/topics/spiders.html?highlight=crawlspider#crawling-rules):

```
Warning
When writing crawl spider rules, avoid using parse as callback, since the CrawlSpider uses the parse method itself to implement its logic. So if you override the parse method, the crawl spider will no longer work.
```

Though you don't use this method within the callback, you *might* override the method from the super class (CrawlSpider). So renamning your parse method might work.

Another issue is that you are not returning an `Item` or `Request` in the your methods

> must return a list containing Item and/or Request objects (or any subclass of them)

None of your methods does this. The [example](http://readthedocs.org/docs/scrapy/en/latest/topics/spiders.html?highlight=rule#crawlspider-example) demonstrates this pretty well. If you override `parse` you still need to return proper Items/Requests.

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't change anything

Comment: @AsTeR Made another guess ;) See my edit if this works for you.

Comment: Thanks. No it does not, calling parent raise an Exception : exceptions.NotImplementedError. I think parse method implementation is let to subclasses.

Comment: @AsTeR, are you sure you haven't switched to BasePsider from CrawlSpider?

Comment: I've double checked, the code in the is the one I've in my question.

Comment: Ok thanks, the problem with my first try to call parent call was I use super... I update your question with the working code.

Comment: try to remove parse function in your spider

Comment: Hey, I know its a quite old thread, I just had a question, why parse must return an item and/or response?